# how to change forecolor of label inside disabled panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In my project i have panel 1 which include many labels , By default when i run the application my panel.enable should be false but the fore color for labels are going to black , how i can this color is the panel is disabled.

I have tried the below code on Load but it didn't work

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.Enabled == false)
    {
        label13.ForeColor = Color.Gold;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say `panel.enable` *should* be false. Have you debugged the above code to prove this is the case?

Comment: yes i do , it's already false but the color didn't change

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the `SystemColors` instead of something like `Color.Black`.
If you hard-code specific color values, they will often conflict when the user customizes their default Windows theme. [Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071212-00/?p=24203/) discusses the perils of this in an article on his blog

You should change the line:

```
 label13.ForeColor = Color.Gold;
```

To:

```
 label13.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Gold);
```

I hope you've found it helpful